# socket.io - socket.send doesn't communicate message

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to communicate text between front and back end.
My `node.js` code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8081);

app.use(express.static('public'));

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at', port);

  io.sockets.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
  });

});
```

The markup:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8081');
          socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.send('hi');
          });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am pretty new to socket.io, and `socket.send('hi')` should be `console.log`ing `hi` to the node console.
Is there something I am missing (yes, the IP is right)?
There are no JS console errors.

Comment: Instead of using `socket.send('hi')` try `socket.emit('hi')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `io.sockets.on` -- you can only use it to `.emit` to connected sockets.

Additionally, for the frontend the event when the socket connects is `connect`. `connection` is the server side event for when a new connection is created.

Finally, the `socket` is not passed as an argument to the event on the frontend either.

```
// server
io.on('connection', socket => socket.on('message', msg => console.log(msg)));

// client
socket.on('connect', () => socket.send('hi'));
```

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth you may be using a version of node older then 4; just replace it with the normal `function` syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I'm confused about changing `=>` to functions. I would assume `socket => socket.on(//other stuff here);` is the same as `function (socket) {socket.on(other stuff here)};`. But that isn't working.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth because as I said, `socket` is not passed as an argument to the event. Don't pass anything. You are overwriting the socket.

Comment: even adding a function and not passing anything in, returns `unexpected token`.

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge, just updated to `node 4` and with the code you originally gave me, I am getting `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth create a github gist of your file and I will correct it for you, but I recommend you learn to lint and debug on your own as well.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth updated my answer; I had missed a comma

Comment: ah, sorry for not catching that. segmentation fault, I suppose from updating to node 4 without changing dependencies.